# Java Generics Assignment

Tags: java, generics

I have a Assignment question about Java Generics. The given class is Product.java. It has abstract class Product, then ComputerPart, Peripheral, Fruit,  Cheese, and Service extends Product.

1. Carefully study the class structure in Products.java.
2. Design a generic container called GenericOrder that acts as a collection of an arbitrary number of objects in Products.java. Design a mechanism that gives each instance of the container a unique identifier. Implement as many methods as necessary. You must use Java generics features.
3. Design and implement a subclass of GenericOrder called ComputerOrder that takes an arbitrary number of different classes of ComputerPart objects, Peripheral objects, and Service objects. Implement as many methods as necessary.
4. Design and implement a subclass of GenericOrder called PartyTrayOrder that takes an arbitrary number of different classes of Cheese objects, Fruit objects, and Service objects. Implement as many methods as necessary.
5. Design and implement a class called OrderProcessor. You must implement at least the following methods:

   ```
   accept; // this method accepts a GenericOrder or any of its subclass objects and stores it in any internal collection of OrderProcessor.


   process; // this method sorts all accepted orders in the internal collection of GenericOrder into collections of ComputerPart, Peripheral, Cheese, Fruit, and Service. You must associate each object with the unique identifier. You may refer to the TwoTuple.java example in the text book.


   dispatchXXX; // this method simulates the dispatch of the sorted collections. For example, the method dispatchComputerParts() should produce this output:


   Motherboard  name=Asus, price=$37.5, order number=123456


   Motherboard  name=Asus, price=$37.5, order number=987654


   RAM  name=Kingston, size=512, price=$25.0, order number=123456


   You may overload each of the above methods as you think necessary.
   ```
6. Create a client class to test OrderProcessor. You will need to create a datagenerator for testing purpose. It is not mandatory but you may use a variation of Data Generator in TIJ pages 637 to 638.
7. Pack the above codes into one single zip file and send it to your tutor.

I have done the 1 requirment, but I have trouble to understand 2nd one. Here is the code I did:

```
public class GenericOrder<T> {
    private static long counter = 1;
    private final long id = counter++;
    private List<T> products;
    private T theClass;

    public GenericOrder() 
    {
        products = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addProduct(T newProduct) {
        products.add(newProduct);

    }

    public int getNumberOfProducts() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public List<T> getProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<T> products)
    {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public T get()
    {
        return theClass;
    }

    public void set(T theClass)
    {
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }
}
public class ComputerOrder<T> extends GenericOrder<T> {
    private List<T> products; 
    private T theClass;

    public ComputerOrder() 
    {
        products = new ArrayList<T>();
    }


    public void addProduct(T newProduct) {
        products.add(newProduct);

    }

    public int getNumberOfProducts() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public List<T> getProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<T> products)
    {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public T get()
    {
        return theClass;
    }

    public void set(T theClass)
    {
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }
}
```

Please help me out here, see if anyone understand 2nd requirement better than I do.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part two is looking for a class that has an upper bound type restriction, so perhaps something like this:

```
public class ComputerOrder<T extends Product> extends GenericOrder<T> {
    // etc...
}
```

**Edit**

I missed the Fruit and Cheese classes. In order for type bounding to work, you would most likely need to code your computer products to an interface and use the following:

```
public class ComputerOrder<T implements MyInterface> extends GenericOrder<T> {
    // etc...
}
```

For more information on bounded type parameters, read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: if T only extends Product, then why does it ask specifically ComputerOrder that takes an arbitrary number of different classes of ComputerPart objects, Peripheral objects, and Service objects

Comment: @Jack: Notice that your GenericOrder class accepts any type. ComputerOrder, however, only allows types that extend your Product class. Since Product is abstract, the Product class itself cannot be instantiated. It can only be initialized using types that extend it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tyler. One last question, if the Product.java also has Fruit and Cheese which also extends Product, but ComputerOrder doesn't take Fruit and Cheese Object. What should I do?

Comment: No to be disrespectful, I don't think I need to create a Interface here. This is a course assignment, I think it will give me hint if it asks for a Interface. But I will keep what u said in mind.

Comment: I don't see any other viable way to restrict the types. A Cheese class and a ComputerPart class are very different from each other. I'm not sure what the guidelines of the assignment are exactly, but it would make sense to have interfaces or abstract classes that describe similar products, i.e. a ComputerProduct class and a FoodProduct class, which further extend the Product class, or something of that nature.

Comment: Hi Tyler, I just put my entire Assignment specs up. It will give you a better idea about my questions. If you have any further comments, please let me know. Again, thanks for you time.

Comment: I would make two abstract classes, ComputerProduct and PartyTrayProduct, both extending Product. Then all you'd have to do is `public class ComputerOrder<T extends ComputerProduct> extends GenericOrder<T>`. It might not be the solution you're looking for, but it's the best solution I can think of at the moment. Good luck!

Comment: Acctually this is what I thought too, it's just I never done generics before, and this is distance learning. so i need all the help i can get. Thanks again.

Comment: hey jack I have the same assignment as this how did you restrict the type to  specific classes? I dont get how the creating an abstract class would restrict the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Tyler beat me to it, but I just wanted to add that you don't need to override all those methods... they're already provided for you in the base class.

What you should add are methods that are common to the ComputerParts and Peripherals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
interface CO{} //for computer orders 
interface PTO{} //party tray orders
        
class ComputerPart implements CO{} 
class Peripheral implements CO{}      
class Fruits implements PTO{} 
class Cheese implements PTO{}     
class Service implements CO, PTO{}
public static class ComputerOrders<T extends CO> extends GenericOrder{}  
public static class PartyTrayOrder <T extends PTO> extends GenericOrder {}
```